# Не работает маска для ввода номера, подгрузка input через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, маска

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://domen.com/maska"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://domen.com/js/form.js"></script>
<div class="form_call"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Далее сама form.js

```js
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js';
  script.async = false; 
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  var script_native = document.createElement('script');
  script_native.src = 'https://domen.com/script.js';
  script_native.async = false; 
  document.head.appendChild(script_native);
```

script.js, где уже используется ajax

```js
var formHTML_link1 = 'https://domen.com/form_html.php';


$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: formHTML_link1,
    success: function(html) {
      $('.form_call').append(html);
      adaptiveNativecall();
    }
  });

});
```

Ну и сам инпут по адресу https://domen.com/form_html.php, который и выводится

```html
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
  <input id="apply-phone-mask" type="text" placeholder="+7(___) ___-__-__">
```

В итоге маска не работает с этим инпутом, никак не могу понять почему. Хелп плиз!

Comment: Не понятно, что внутри script.js и почему маска должна работать. Попробуйте залить пример на jsfiddle вместе с файлом script.js и покажите то место, где вызываете выполнение маски.

Comment: 3ий код сверху, там код, находящийся в script.js

Comment: Используется метод `adaptiveNativecall();`, только не видно его описание. Возможно это он должен применять маску, но не понятно. Попробуйте воспользоваться другими библиотеками для задания маски, например https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

Comment: adaptiveNativecall(); забыл вырезать, он ни на что относящееся к вопросу не влияет.  Маска инициируется здесь <script src="https://domen.com/maska"></script>

Comment: Если поставить <input id="apply-phone-mask" type="text" placeholder="+7(___) ___-__-__"> просто в body, то маска работает

Comment: Смотрите, у меня есть предположение, что функция добавления маски вызывается на момент загрузки страницы ДО добавления элемента `input` в DOM. Поэтому попробуйте вызвать эту функцию ПОСЛЕ его добавление. 1) Если `input` загружается в DOM на момент загрузки страницы, то код вызова маски стоит поместить в блок `$(document).ready(function(){ /* here */ });`. Подробнее - http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ . 2) Если `input` добавляется динамически на страницу, то вызов функции маски следует повторно вызывать, например, в *callback* методе после добавления элемента.